# Is there any way to namespace PL/SQL packages?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, package

I have several different packages, one for each logical part of my application.  Some packages are getting huge but I would like to keep all the procedures/functions grouped in some way rather than breaking them into separate packages.  Is there any way to nest, or namespace, my packages?

So if I have `MYSCHEMA.PKG_PEOPLE` and it has 10 procedures and 10 functions, is there no way that I can for instance move the CRUD procedures to `MYSCHEMA.PKG_PEOPLE.CRUD`.  I want to keep all these items inside of `PKG_PEOPLE` but I want to further sub-divide them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Beyond Schema and Package, there is no multi-level namespace handling for PL/SQL packages in Oracle.

Within a package body you can define nested procedures but I would guess this isn't what you need.

I think the closest you'll get is to enforce a naming rule on your packages. For example:

```
MYSCHEMA.PKG_PEOPLE
MYSCHEMA.PKG_PEOPLE_CRUD
```